# Field axioms in Mathematica

Tags: logic, field-theory

I don't understand the result of

```
AxiomaticTheory["FieldAxioms", "Axioms"]
```

> `{ForAll[{\[FormalA], \[FormalB], \[FormalC]}, \[FormalA] \[CirclePlus] (\[FormalB] \[CirclePlus] \[FormalC]) \[Tilde] (\[FormalA] \[CirclePlus] \[FormalB]) \[CirclePlus] \[FormalC]],  ForAll[{\[FormalA], \[FormalB]}, \[FormalA] \[CirclePlus] \[FormalB] \[Tilde] \[FormalB] \[CirclePlus] \[FormalA]], ForAll[\[FormalA], \[FormalA] \[CirclePlus] OverTilde[0] \[Tilde] \[FormalA]],  ForAll[\[FormalA], \[FormalA] \[CirclePlus] OverBar[\[FormalA]] \[Tilde] OverTilde[0]], ForAll[{\[FormalA], \[FormalB], \[FormalC]},  \[FormalA] \[CircleTimes] (\[FormalB] \[CirclePlus] \[FormalC]) \[Tilde] \[FormalA] \[CircleTimes] \[FormalB] \[CirclePlus] \[FormalA] \[CircleTimes] \[FormalC]], ForAll[\[FormalA], \[FormalA] \[Tilde] \[FormalA]],  ForAll[{\[FormalA], \[FormalB]}, Implies[\[FormalA] \[Tilde] \[FormalB], \[FormalB] \[Tilde] \[FormalA]]], ForAll[{\[FormalA], \[FormalB], \[FormalC]},  Implies[\[FormalA] \[Tilde] \[FormalB] && \[FormalB] \[Tilde] \[FormalC], \[FormalA] \[Tilde] \[FormalC]]], ForAll[{\[FormalA], \[FormalB], \[FormalC]},  \[FormalA] \[CircleTimes] (\[FormalB] \[CircleTimes] \[FormalC]) \[Tilde] (\[FormalA] \[CircleTimes] \[FormalB]) \[CircleTimes] \[FormalC]], ForAll[{\[FormalA], \[FormalB]}, \[FormalA] \[CircleTimes] \[FormalB] \[Tilde] \[FormalB] \[CircleTimes] \[FormalA]],  ForAll[\[FormalA], \[FormalA] \[CircleTimes] OverTilde[1] \[Tilde] \[FormalA]], ForAll[\[FormalA], Implies[ !\[FormalA] \[Tilde] OverTilde[0],  \[FormalA] \[CircleTimes] SuperMinus[\[FormalA]] \[Tilde] OverTilde[1]]]}`

First, I see 12 axioms, but I was taught there are 9 field axioms and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) confirms that. Second, I don't understand the axiom `ForAll[\[FormalA], \[FormalA] \[Tilde] \[FormalA]]` at all.

Can somebody shed a light on it?

Comment: Sorry if I point out the obvious, but it seems to denote equality by `\[Tilde]`, and include some [axioms for the equality sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Basic_properties). Maybe that explains the discrepancy.

Comment: @user293787: Thank you for interest to the question. Unfortunately. this does not explain why two other  properties of equality ( symmetry and transitivity) are not included in `"FieldAxioms"`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Actually they are. The three axioms `AxiomaticTheory["FieldAxioms","Axioms"][[{6,7,8}]]` are, respectively: reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity of equality.

Comment: @user293787: Thank you. I should be more careful. The questions arise: why `AxiomaticTheory["RingAxioms", "Axioms"]` does not include those? what is the difference between `\[Tilde]` and `==`?

Answer (score 0):

$\{\forall_{a,b,c}a\oplus(b\oplus c)\sim (a\oplus b)\oplus c\, ...\}$
is not what is in these axioms. The letters are not latin but [FormalA](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/FormalA.html). This says about the symbol [FormalA](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/FormalA.html):

"Used to represent a formal parameter that will never be assigned a value."

So with the question for TeX letter $\sim$ this is not done. A discussion can be found [how-do-i-write-sim-approximately-with-the-correct-spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55701/how-do-i-write-sim-approximately-with-the-correct-spacing). A much broader interpretation set can be found on [help TeX](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilfe:TeX).

A proper one-to-one transformation into common well in use terms can be found using the Wolfram Alpha prompt like

[image: field axioms]

You might use

```
AxiomaticTheory["FieldAxioms","Operators"]
```

(*[LeftAssociation]Addition->CirclePlus,AdditionInverse->OverBar,AdditionIdentity->OverscriptBox["0", "~"],Equivalence->Tilde,Multiplication->CircleTimes,MultiplicationInverse->SuperMinus,MultiplicationIdentity->OverscriptBox["1", "~"][RightAssociation]  *)

Do

```
AxiomaticTheory["FieldAxioms", "Dataset"]
```

Click on AxiomsAssociations

[image: AxiomsAssociations]

So these are indeed 12. The full dataset has the property AxiomsAssociations. Therein the names of the axioms are given a literally of value name.

Here is an example online how the field axioms are taught at present times in introductory university courses: [2.3 The field axioms](http://people.reed.edu/%7Emayer/math112.html/html1/node16.html).

This is some more light perhaps: [using field axioms for a simple proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650739/using-field-axioms-for-a-simple-proof)

So additional to the triple $\{F,\oplus,\otimes\}$ there is a fourth at least binary interpretable symbol $\sim$. $\sim$ can be replace by equal. As the other symbols this is restrict to symbolics only. This offers more flexibility for advance proofs. That is quite common for Mathematica built-ins.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand even the first sentence "$\{\forall_{a,b,c}a\oplus(b\oplus c)\sim (a\oplus b)\oplus c\, ...\}$ is not was is in these axioms".

Comment: This in no way answers the question that was asked.

Comment: I can not know what field axioms are taught to him. He did not give in his question.

Comment: I expect at least he had not been taught computational symbolics. This is in the sense of the question "some" light. After some recherche I expect this to be duplicate: [implementing the field axioms with findequationalproof](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172950/implementing-the-field-axioms-with-findequationalproof)!

Comment: First hypothesis is, they did not subsume the equivalence axioms to the field axioms by arithmetic.